# Disable Context Menu with WindowChrome.WindowChrome

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, prism, wpftoolkit

I am unable to disable ContextMenu, if I use WindowChrome.WindowChrome style.
Please let me know your input to resolve this problem.
Without WindowChrome i am able to disable context menu with same piece of code.

```
    <Window x:Class="ConextMenu_Sample.MainWindow"                
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
        <WindowChrome.WindowChrome>
            <WindowChrome CaptionHeight="35"
                          CornerRadius="0"
                          ResizeBorderThickness="5"
                          UseAeroCaptionButtons="False" />
        </WindowChrome.WindowChrome>
        <Grid>

        </Grid>
    </Window>
```

Code behind

```
        public partial class MainWindow : Window
        {
            private const uint WP_SYSTEMMENU = 0x02;
            private const uint WM_SYSTEMMENU = 0xa4;
            public MainWindow()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                Loaded += OnLoaded;
            }

            private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {
                IntPtr windIntPtr = new WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle;
                HwndSource hwndSource = HwndSource.FromHwnd(windIntPtr);
                hwndSource.AddHook(new HwndSourceHook(WndProc));
            }

            private IntPtr WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam, ref bool handled)
            {
                if ((msg == WM_SYSTEMMENU) && (wparam.ToInt32() == WP_SYSTEMMENU))
                {
                    handled = true;
                }
                return IntPtr.Zero;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use this Code:**

U need to set the windowstyle property None.

**Property:-** WindowStyle = "None"

```
<Window x:Class="ConextMenu_Sample.MainWindow" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" WindowStyle="None">
```

**[OR]**

```
private IntPtr WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam, ref bool handled)
        {
            if ((msg == WM_SYSTEMMENU) && (wparam.ToInt32() == WP_SYSTEMMENU))
            {
                handled = false;  // Change the Boolean Value to false // 
            }
            return IntPtr.Zero;
        }
```

Comment: It's not working,  <WindowChrome.WindowChrome> when we have this item,   WindowStyle="None" doesn't have ant impact

Comment: @user3571518 - or try this code change the boolean value to false it will work

Comment: I need <WindowChrome.WindowChrome> for other activities. above solution, won't solve my problem

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you didn't need this,but I solved it and want to share it to someone need it.

```
if (((msg == WM_SYSTEMMENU) && (wParam.ToInt32() == WP_SYSTEMMENU)) || msg == 165){
    //ShowContextMenu();
    handled = true;
}
```

Comment: I've been looking for an answer all day. This one solved it finally.