# Disable contxtmenu if we use <windowchrome.windowchrome>

Tags: wpf

I have the same problem as this previous post:
[Disable Context Menu with WindowChrome.WindowChrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42778240/disable-context-menu-with-windowchrome-windowchrome)
I have window with :
<WindowChrome.WindowChrome > and WindowStyle="None"
I want to remove the right click OS context menu
I haven't found a solution.
i tried the following code but is does not work:

```
private IntPtr WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled)
    {
        if (((msg == WM_SYSTEMMENU) && (wParam.ToInt32() == WP_SYSTEMMENU)) || msg ==165)
        {
           
            handled = true;
        }

        return IntPtr.Zero;
        
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need caption, then setting CaptionHeight="0" should solve your problem.

```
<WindowChrome.WindowChrome>
    <WindowChrome CaptionHeight="0"/>
</WindowChrome.WindowChrome>
```

Comment: I need the caption.

Comment: You could make a caption by yourself, must be not too complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        SourceInitialized += (s, e) => 
            HwndSource.FromHwnd(new WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle)
               .AddHook(new HwndSourceHook(WndProc));
    }

    private IntPtr WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled)
    {
        if (msg == 0xa5 && wParam.ToInt32() == 0x02)
            handled = true;

        return IntPtr.Zero;
    }
}
```

It seems to work for me.